# Adding root to a group

Tags: linux, permissions, user-profiles

I am not new to Linux, but there's this strange behaviour I'm seeing on my Fedora 15 box. I want to add the superuser to a group called, say, `thisgroup`.

```
# usermod -a -G thisgroup root
# groups
# root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel
#
```

^^ `thisgroup` is absent. Surprisingly, when I thought of editing `/etc/group`, `root` was present there!

Anyone on why `groups` didn't show my new addition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the manpage of the `groups` command:

```
Print  group memberships for each USERNAME or, if no USERNAME is speci‐
fied, for the current process (which may differ if the groups  database
has changed)
```

This is exactly your case: the group database has changed, but the group membership for the current process hasn't been updated. If you instead queried the group memberships for the `root` user you would have got the correct result.

```
matteo@teomint:~$ sudo usermod -a -G test matteo
matteo@teomint:~$ groups
matteo adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
matteo@teomint:~$ groups matteo
matteo : matteo adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare test
```

Long story short: for the current process, `root` isn't member of `thisgroup` yet; you have to login again.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work without logging out and logging in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to logout and in again - with no argument the `groups` command prints the groups that the current process has which doesn't change when when you change the group database.

If you do `groups root` then you should see it listed as that consults the `/etc/group` file.